# How to upload large files from local pc to DBFS?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to learn spark SQL in databricks and want to work with the Yelp dataset; however, the file is too large to upload to DBFS from UI. Thanks, Filip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches to that:

1. Use Databricks CLI's [dbfs command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli.html) to upload local data to DBFS.
2. Download dataset directly from notebook, for example by using `%sh wget URL`, and unpacking the archive to DBFS (either by using `/dbfs/path/...` as destination, or using `dbutils.fs.cp` command to copy files from driver node to DBFS)
3. Upload files to AWS S3, Azure Data Lake Storage, Google Storage or something like, and accessing data there.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file you want to load in Databricks to google drive

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from shutil import copyfileobj

my_url = 'paste your url here'
my_filename = 'give your filename'
file_path = '/FileStore/tables' # location at which you want to move the downloaded file

# Downloading the file from google drive to Databrick

with urlopen(my_url) as in_stream, open(my_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    copyfileobj(in_stream, out_file)

# check where the file has download
# in my case it is

display(dbutils.fs.ls('file:/databricks/driver'))

# moving the file to desired location
# dbutils.fs.mv(downloaded_location, desired_location)

dbutils.fs.mv("file:/databricks/driver/my_file", file_path)
```

I hope this helps